# php driver for mongodb error

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am trying to install the php driver for mongodb as described in this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/).
I have downloaded the drivers from gitHub, I tried all the 5.3 versions and I am getting this error: `%1 is not a valid win32 application` (the error pops out when starting apache on exampp). I have added the needed row in the ini file.
Here is the screen shot of my php version:[image]

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you should be installing the dll with `-5.3-vc9.dll` at the end. This should be renamed php_mongo.dll and added to the extensions folder.

Comment: @Derick I hardly ever use PHP on windows, thanks for clarifying.